# Ember-cli ignores brocfile.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

So basically I described my problem in the subject of this post :). Brocfile.js content is like that:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp();

app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff', {
    destDir: 'fonts'
});

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

but when I put some content that don't make much sense, like

`1--==++` I'm not getting any error, so my reasoning is that ember-cli just doesn't give a s**t about this file :). Funny thing is that I just updated ember-cli, and now it's version is 1.13.1 (and ember.js version is 1.13.3) and before the update everything worked fine.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't give a s**t about it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade path for `1.13.0` stated a need to rename the brocfile.

**`Brocfile.js` has been deprecated in favor of `ember-cli-build.js`. See TRANSITION.md for details on how to transition your `Brocfile.js` code to `ember-cli-build.js`.**

http://www.ember-cli.com/#section-1

Comment: Yep, that worked :). My opinion is that they should emphasize it a bit more - maybe set up some information after the `ember upgrade` command finishes, or something like that.

Comment: totally, some sort of deprecation warning would have been nice.